# Using JAXB creating xml file

Tags: java, jaxb

please bellow tag  how can create xml file using JAxb please.Like same sequence Output Iam not getting.In Data node I want text,one image again one text node

```
<data>
    <text>
        hello
    </text>
    <image name="b99d.png">Imagefile name</image> 
    <text>
        world 
    </text>
</data>
```

Comment: look at this post http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: Ya i created xml file but i need the output text,image,again text tag sequence i am not getting

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the image and text data stored in a single `List`.  Once you have done this there are a couple of options.

---

**OPTION #1**

You could use the `@XmlElements`

```
public class Data {

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="text", type=String.class),
        @XmlElement(name="image", type=Image.class)
    })
    public List<Object> getTextAndImages() {
        return textAndImages;
    }
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html

---

**OPTION #2**

You could also leverage the `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` annotation on a **single** `List` property to map this use case.  The contents of the `List` property will be instances of `Text` and `Image`.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({Image.class, Text.class})
public class Data {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    public List<Object> getTextAndImages() {
        return textAndImages;
    }
}
```

Each of these classes will need to be annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. The `@XmlValue` annotation will be useful when creating the mappings for the `Text` and `Image` classes.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Text {

    @XmlValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxbs-xmlanyelementlaxtrue-explained.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Comment: please i need above order multiple text,like text one image again one text ,please tel me how can i do

Comment: @user1906191 - You will need to have one `List` property that contains different types of objects.  The instance of `List` will be responsible for maintaining the correct order.

Comment: Ya but list will dispaly continously but i want text tag again image tag once again text.please it is possible or not in jaxB

Comment: @user1906191 - Have you tried anything I have suggested so far?

Comment: Ya if I set in List means It will display continuously same tag like <text><text><image>   but i want in xml like <text> <image><text> this type order I am not getting

Comment: @user1906191 - In my approach there is only one `List`.  I have updated my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: @user1906191: Please at least up-vote Blaise's answer as you'll get no better here or on any site.